# Save data in an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 activities, 1st is to get an image from the user. the second activity gets data from google maps. But if I use intent to call 2nd activity from the first one, and another intent to go back to the first activity the data is gone. Is there any possible way to save the image and the returned data from the second activity?

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: take a look at `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` on how to return data from an `Activity` using `putExtras`

Comment: You might want to save data to the internal storage, see the [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options available.  Perhaps the most accessible to you right now would be to use shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.your.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
byte[] image;  // populate this byte array with your image
String key = "myimagekey";
String imgString = new String(image, "UTF-8");
prefs.edit().putString(key, imgString).apply();
```

This stores a byte array containing your image as a string.  Then, in the next activity, you may retrieve it via:

```
String img = prefs.getString(key, null);
```

Another option, perhaps more work, would be to configure a SQLite database which your app can use.  Then, you can simply insert your image as a BLOB into some table, and then read from that same table in the next activity.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am not sure that all `bytes` in a image can be converted to `Strings`

Comment: @ScaryWombat You're right, and I updated to use UTF-8 encoding, which is probably safe here.

Answer (score 0):

You could save images or large data to the internal storage [(android doc)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage) or save other kinds of smaller data such as arraylists, objects into shared preferences with gson (for that see [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcliHGR3CHo&t=1s)).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want, depending on the circumstances.

The most common scenario (which is what yours sounds like) is when a child Activity is used to get user input - such as choosing a contact from a list or entering data in a dialog box. In this case you should use [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to launch your child Activity.

This provides a pipeline for sending data back to the main Activity using [`setResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29). The setResult method takes an int result value and an Intent that is passed back to the calling Activity.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
// TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
resultIntent.putExtra("some_key", "String data"); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

To access the returned data in the calling Activity override `onActivityResult`. The requestCode corresponds to the integer passed in in the `startActivityForResult` call, while the resultCode and data Intent are returned from the child Activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
    case (MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // TODO Extract the data returned from the child Activity.
        String returnValue = data.getStringExtra("some_key");
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
}
```